# Why Rust fails when I try to implement recursion with "S I I" from SKI-calculus?

Tags: recursion, rust, lambda-calculus

Note: I took definitions of `S` and `I` from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description

So `S xyz = xz(yz)`, or in Rust:

```rust
fn s <Z, Y, X> (
    x: fn(Z) -> fn(Y) -> X,
    y: fn(Z) -> Y,
    z: Z
) -> X
where Z: Copy
{
    x(z)(y(z))
}
```

Let's also define an auxiliary `I x = x`:

```rust
fn i <X> (x: X) -> X { x }
```

I know that `S I I x` is `x(x)`(the problem I'm actually trying to solve is finding a type of `x` such that `x` is applicable to itself.), but let's not be that generic rn and try to use `S I I I` instead.

Obviously, `S I I I = I(I)(I(I)) = I(I) = I`

```rust
let _ = s(i, i, i); // = i(i)(i(i)) = i(i) = i
```

That is legit in my eyes, but not in compiler's:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:45:18
   |
45 |     let _ = s(i, i, i);
   |             -    ^ cyclic type of infinite size
   |             |
   |             arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
note: function defined here
  --> src/main.rs:32:4
   |
32 | fn s <Z, Y, X> (
   |    ^
33 |     x: fn(Z) -> fn(Y) -> X,
34 |     y: fn(Z) -> Y,
   |     -------------
```

I've found an "explanation" that this error occurs because there's some incalculable type that rustc cannot cope with. Makes sense, but I don't see here any exemplar of said type. May you point to me where it happens(and how to work around it, if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to write the type equations Rust has to solve, to understand what went wrong. Each `i` has type `fn(X) -> X` for a given `X`. Since they can be chosen independently for each `i`, I'll name them `X₁`, `X₂` and `X₃`.

1. The first `i` has type `fn(X₁) -> X₁`, and the expected type was `fn(Z) -> fn(Y) -> X`, so by unification we have `Z = X₁ = fn(Y) -> X` (1).
2. The second `i` has type `fn(X₂) -> X₂`, and the expected type was `fn(Z) -> Y`, so by unification we have `Z = X₂ = Y` (2).
3. The third type equation is `X₃ = Z` (3).

By combining (1) and (2), we have `Y = fn(Y) -> X`. This type equation is cyclic: you will never find a finite type (in Rust's type system, at least) that will satisfy that.

Just as an aside, OCaml can typecheck that, *if you explicitely turn on recursive types with `-rectypes`*:

```ml
# let s x y z = x z (y z) in s Fun.id Fun.id Fun.id;;
- : 'a -> 'a as 'a = <fun>
#
```

If you are exploring lambda calculi, and friends, OCaml might be a better alternative.

As for Rust, I don't think there are any type-friendly way to do this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, now I understand it! I'm not sure that OCaml with its recursive types would be an appropriate choice for me since the very task is to implement the Y-combinator in a strongly typed language and so recursive types look like cheating since if I use recursion to implement recursion... That won't do :)

Comment: @Doubtful I think it's impossible to implement to Y combinator in a type system that does not implement recursion, but I'm not sure why. I was going to add something related to the impossibility of embedding the SKI calculus in Rust like that, but I have to think a little bit about it first. I will edit my answer when I find something meaningful.

Comment: IMO It's not like you can't implement a Y-comb in a non-recursive context, it's more like that this context should not impose some type restrictions.
Simple example: loops-less almost-everything-less Javascript.
It is possible to define Y-comb here (proof: https://benestudio.co/fixed-point-combinators-in-javascript/), so it's all about types...

Comment: @Doubtful you either want to know the types in full in advance, or don't. the first is known as static types discipline, the second as dynamic types discipline. in static type discipline all types must agree with each other, that's how mistakes are detected. with parametric types, this means solving the system of type equations, e.g. from a=b and b=c we conclude a=c as well. so when we see a=b and a=b->c we must conclude b=b->c and see whether this is not self contradictory. since b->c involves two type variables, we look up their definitions. c has none but b is b->c and so it must hold that

Comment: ... b=(b->c)->c=((b->c)->c)->c=... and the check never stops. or we can add a feature to our type system and say, we're fine with such equations, don't check them for us, trust us it's OK. these are the recursive types. it's not cheating with regards to having recursion in the language,it can still forbid it. the types are a separate realm. so to have the non-recursive Y combinator, either don't have types at all ("dynamic typing discipline") or have static type system which allows for recursive type equations. those are the two choices. (as far as I can tell, and I'm not an expert *at all*).

Comment: of course there are more options in between, like gradual typing, etc. what I don't know is how that relates to the problem of typeability of self-applyable terms as we have here.

Comment: @WillNess hmm, okay you convinced me, I'll check the recursive types out)